How to connect to JDBC database using py4j in python lambda?
I wanted to test a JDBC connection using Python lambda in the AWS console. I am using py4j. I added this as a layer for the lambda. I have the following code.
from py4j.java_gateway import *

gg = launch_gateway()

When I run this in AWS console,
getting error:
"could not find py4j jar" for the line gg = launch_gateway().

Where do I add py4j.jar in AWS?
This is a Python lambda function.
How do I fix this issue?

I encountered the same error when following the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-layers.html#python-layer-packaging. To ensure py4j<<version>>.jar was included in my layer I had to modify the 2 shell scripts as follows.
1-install.sh becomes:
python3.11 -m venv create_layer
source create_layer/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt --prefix=vendor
pip install -r requirements.txt

This ensures pip includes dependencies such as the missing py4j<<version>>.jar in an additional directory vendor/share.
2-package.sh becomes:
mkdir python
cp -r create_layer/lib python/
cp -r vendor/share python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/
zip -r layer_content.zip python

This ensures those dependencies are included in the zipfile, which can then be used to create a layer as described in the docs.

Note: It appears aws only included openjdk version "1.8.0_201" up to python 3.7. From 3.8 and upwards it appears java is unavailable in the python runtime environments.
